# Image in React Bootstrap Modal does not update

Tags: javascript, html, image, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn React Js and I've managed to get stuck on an issue that drives me insane. It's pretty specific so sorry for the long question. I'll try to explain it and then share the code.

1. I have a component that contains a **table with employees.**
2. On **every row there is an edit button** that triggers the rendering of a component that only has a React Bootstrap Modal.
3. I'm sending all the employee's row data to the child component through props.
4. The default values of all modal's fields are from the props.

Now, there are 2 scenarios:

1. I got **only one row** in the table, I'll press the edit button and all data from the row is loaded in the modal, even the image is being set fine. When I try to change the image everything is fine, the photo instantly updates.
2. I got **more than one row** in the table, I'll press the edit button from any of the rows and once again, the modal is loaded fine. **The issue** appears when I try to change the **image** from the modal... nothing happens. **BUT** there is a really awkward behaviour that I hardly noticed, when I close the modal, just for a frame, the image changes.

I have really hard time trying to figure out **why** would more rows in the table affect the image updating in the Modal. Or delaying it...

Now, I'll try to share the relevant bits of code and how I update the image and some other code from the component that holds the Modal. I'm sorry for the horrors that will follow.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleFileSelected=this.handleFileSelected.bind(this);
}

photofilename = "anonymous.png";

imagesrc = process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+this.photofilename;

handleFileSelected(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.photofilename=event.target.files[0].name;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
        "myFile",
        event.target.files[0],
        event.target.files[0].name
    );

    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'Employee/SaveFile',{
        method:'POST',
        body:formData
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then((result)=>{
        this.imagesrc=process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+result;
        document.getElementById("img").src = this.imagesrc;
    },
    (error)=>{
        alert('Failed');
    })
}

....
render() {
     return (
          <div className="container"
                 <Modal  
.....
 <Image width="220px" height="220px" 
        src={process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+this.props.photofilename} id="img"/>
 <input onChange={this.handleFileSelected} type="File"/>
```

When the modal loads I first set the src for the image to be the photofilename sent from the table's row, everything is fine. When selecting another image I'll try to force the new src on the image.
Again, when there is only one row in the table it works perfectly, but when there are more rows the image is not updating. I really can't correlate those things.

If needed I can share the github link to the repository.

If anyone can point out my dumb mistake or had a similar issue and share their experience I would highly appreciate it. Thanks and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bit difficult to debug just from your code above, but here are some suggestions. Can you try setting the image source (`imagesrc`) as a state with `useState / useEffect` instead of just changing the image source as a global variable. In case of class component just check: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Maybe also check whats the `result` of the response you are getting and if it does contain the correct value for the image url. You are doing a `res.json()` which returns a json object/value I guess. Is it the correct `url` for the image you are trying to set (maybe should be `result.url` or so)? Please see below:

```
this.imagesrc=process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+result;
```

And I am not sure if you use this imagesrc elsewhere in your code, or only to change the image source in `document.getElementById("img").src = this.imagesrc;`

```
this.imagesrc = process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+result; 
<Image width="220px" height="220px" src={process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+this.props.photofilename} id="img"/>
```

Try changing the `src` of this image above to `imagesrc` directly. So when you update the `imagesrc` state it should also change the source directly.

Comment: To my own stubborness I haven't tried to put it as a state because I wasn't correlating the issue with the fact there is more that 1 row in the table. Anyway, it works now when I'm trying to change the picture but a new problem came up. Let's say I open the first employee in the list for editing, I set any image and then I close the modal. When I open the edit modal again, for any of the employees, the last image shows up, not the actual employee's image. Anyway, this is not such a big issue as I understand what happens now. Thank you a lot for your suggestion! I really really appreciate it.

Comment: I think it is because your `imagesrc = process.env.REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH+this.photofilename;` photofilename is hardcoded. Any time you open the modal. That image would load instad of the new one.